# Is it legal to install hidden cameras in a public place within the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, evidence

In recent years, fly-tipping (dumping domestic/business waste) has become quite prevalent in a number of spots around my area. The local authority has erected numerous very visible signs, warning fly-tippers that cameras are in operation in the area, however they either don't care or know there likely are no actual cameras; since the signs were installed there has been tens of large rubbish loads left in the same locations. I'd estimate we are approaching the 30th load by now.

I'm planning to install cameras of my own in one of the hot-spots which is a confluence between a public road, a public bridleway and privately owned farm land (the road turns into a bridleway and is flanked on each side by the farmland). The cameras themselves would be carefully concealed at two or three points on the road. My intention is to collect video evidence according to the proper standards and then pass that onto the local authority and the police.

Would the installation of these cameras be legal? Considering that there are numerous very high visibility signs telling people that CCTV is in operation in the area due to fly-tipping - including one right at the start of the dead end lane which leads to the hotspot. One key point is that *I didn't put up the sings myself*, and the local authority will have no knowledge of what I'm doing until I pass the footage onto them.

Comment: On this site, we cannot and will not give people specific legal advice. For that, one must consult a lawyer or other relevant professional. So that questions do not fall under this limitation, it is better if they are phrased as hypotheticals: that is asking what the law permits or requires in a specific situation. In particular it is a poor idea to ask what you **should** do in a particular situation, that is likely to be legal advice.

Answer (score 3):

### Do you own the land?

Placing your stuff on property you don’t own without permission is … illegal dumping.

Comment: I'll take your answer at face value. If you'd read my question properly you'd see that I'm asking if it is legal to install hidden cameras in a *public* place. So no, I don't own the land but I know who owns the land on either side, and I'm sure they would be more than happy to oblige if I asked for their permission to put cameras there, considering they have to move all the junk to gain access to their fields every time someone dumps another load.

Comment: @nohatsatthetable unless you are the government, you don’t own the street.

Comment: By your logic @DaleM, locking your bike in a public place is illegal dumping. This answer doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @Ray permission can be implicit.